# jQuery how convert it to JSON?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have array:

```
var tab = [];
...
   var dane = [];
   dane['przedmiot'] = przedmiot.text();
   dane['godzina'] = idGodziny;
   dane['dzien'] = dzien;
   tab.push(dane);
...
```

I want send it via ajax by POST so i want convert it to JSON? how do it?

Comment: The `dane` variable should be an object: `var dane = {};` (because you're assigning properties to it that have non-integer names)

Comment: then when i send it i see [Object object]

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Comment: I just want easy read this data in php, when there i can ease read this like tab[1]['przedmiot] or something equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem using another library:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

```
var tab = [];
...
   var dane = {};
   dane['przedmiot'] = przedmiot.text();
   dane['godzina'] = idGodziny;
   dane['dzien'] = dzien;
   var enc = $.toJSON(dane);
   tab.push(enc);
...
//before sending
var encoded = $.toJSON(tab);
```

and i send encoded in post

Answer (score 2):

First, use an object (not an array) for `dane` since your assigning key/values, like this:

```
var dane = {};
dane['przedmiot'] = przedmiot.text();
dane['godzina'] = idGodziny;
dane['dzien'] = dzien;
tab.push(dane);
```

Then, to send your object (`tab`) as JSON, use `JSON.stringify(tab)`, for example:

```
$.post("myPage.something", JSON.stringify(tab));
```

For older browsers (IE7 and below) that don't support `JSON` natively, [include `json2.js`](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery inbuilt function *.serializeArray()*
for more details check this link

[link text](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)